# mfp cordova : Implementation for this cordova subcommand has failed or not been provided: undefined

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

Just downloaded the latest build of mobile first 7.1 cli (Version - 7.1.0.00.20170710-0611) and finished installing in my Mac OS - Sierra 10.12.5

> mfp cordova[image: Error when running mfp cordova commands]
>
> mfp cordova platform list -d
>   [image: Error when running mfp cordova platform list -d command]

Comment: Do you happen to have multiple npm/cli/node versions on the same machine?

Comment: Node version is v6.11.0 and npm is 3.10.10. I don't have multiple versions. Apparently the MFP CLI v7.1.0.00.20160528-1651 doesn't have this issue. I  was able to install and check using v7.1.0.00.20160528-1651.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exactly error, but I'm manual and it work
- Change resources.ts in /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/mfp_cordova_cmds/lib -> line 71

```
if (project && project2 && project3 && project4 && path.dirname(project) === path.dirname(project2) &&
```

if get error with MFP_CORDOVA_PATH not set
-> vim ~/.bash_profile

```
export IBM_CLI_HOME=/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI
export MFP_CORDOVA_PATH=$IBM_CLI_HOME/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/cordovacmd/cordova
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$MFP_CORDOVA_PATH
```

-> source ~/.bash_profile to apply change, you can command 'echo $MFP_CORDOVA_PATH' to check

Try mfp cordova create again